# SQL Server 2016 install configuration domain account not added to SeManageVolumePrivilege

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, installation

I've installed several SQL Server 2016 SP1 servers with the use of a configuration file but I noticed that the service account is not added to 'Perform Volume Maintenace Tasks'. Instead the user 'NT Service\MSSQLServer' is added.

In my ini-file I used following parameters:

```
SQLSVCACCOUNT="domain\user"
SQLSVCINSTANTFILEINIT="True"
```

Is this a known bug in the installer or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I've used .ini files for a number of 2016 installs with domain service accounts and this has worked correctly.